# Unterminated string literal - passing php variable to javascript function, from onclick handler, in echo block

Tags: php, string, echo, literals

Getting an unterminated string literal error with this code.  It works fine, but the error makes me think I'm doing something wrong.  $Filearray has been filled with filenames, and for each one it prints a div block which calls "makeLightbox" when clicked.  I can't see any unterminated string literals here, but it could be me passing the php variables incorrectly.  Any ideas?

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberFiles; $i++)
{
  $file = $fileArray[$i];
  echo ("
          <div class=\"block\">
            <img src=\"$file\" class='thumb' onclick=\"makeLightbox('$file')\") \" />
          </div>
       ");
}
```

Comment: What is the output in browser view source?

Comment: @Esailija `code` <img src="Images/handsandfeet.jpg" class="thumb" onclick="makeLightbox('Images/handsandfeet.jpg')"> `code`

Comment: That code doesn't cause the error then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode PHP variables as JSON before outputting in order to turn them into valid JavaScript literals.

e.g.

```
var s = <?php echo json_encode($val); ?>
```